# Django passing object ID in hiddeninput by populating

Tags: django

I have an form which allows a user to edit an object description. 
How can I  populate an  object ID in a form's hidden input value.
What I done so far is I added an field called hidden_field in forms.py but it only show the hidden_field . How can I link the hidden_field with the object ID

models.py

```
class School(models.Model):


    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class SchoolDescriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,max_length=300)
        hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = School 
        fields = ()
```

views.py

```
def SchoolEditor(request,school_id):


    school = School.objects.get(pk=school_id,user=request.user)
    form = SchoolDescriptionForm(instance=school) # I want to populate the object ID 

    return render(request,'schooleditor.html',{'school':school,'form':form})
```

template

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type = "submit" value= "save" />
{{ form.field.as_hidden }}
 </form>
```

Comment: what is not working here?

Comment: If it doesn't make sense , you can at least give me tips on how to improve on the question

Comment: @RickyA , I want to populate the object ID in the hidden form . Do you kind of get the question?

Comment: `{{ form.hidden_field }}`

Comment: @limelights , <input type="hidden" name="hidden_field" id="id_hidden_field" /> this is what appears on the template . Their no value . I'm just having trouble adding the value in

Comment: in your views.py `form.hidden_field = "monkey"`.

Comment: @limelights form = SchoolDescriptionForm(instance=school) . Okay you see , the form is been populated with the  school = School.objects.get . On the template , I can see the description field been populated but I want to also populate the hidden field from the school object

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm causing any trouble , This is my best explaination . If anyone has trouble understanding the problem . Please tell me so I can adjust it

Comment: @Jacob No worries, you have no matching field in `School` that is called `hidden_field` therefore it won't get populated when you do `form(instance=school)`.

Comment: @Jacob yes, in your `views.py` -> `form.hidden_field = school.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change hidden_field to id and tell Django to include the School's id.

```
class SchoolDescriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,max_length=300)
        id          = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = School 
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to conserve hidden_field as name you should then add a custom init method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SchoolDescriptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance:
        self.fields['hidden_field'].initial = instance.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the object id in the form `initial`:

```
def SchoolEditor(request,school_id):
    initial = {}
    school = School.objects.get(pk=school_id,user=request.user)
    if school:
        initial.update({'hidden_field': school.id})
    form = SchoolDescriptionForm(instance=school, initial=initial) # I want to populate the object ID 

    return render(request,'schooleditor.html',{'school':school,'form':form})
```